# how use the Cron Syntax for node-cron

Tags: node.js, express, cron, node-cron

I'm trying to execute once a cron job in nodejs with express, with the follow code:

```
const cron = require("node-cron");
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const event = new EventEmitter();
...
let task: any = {};
const taskName = newFileName.split(".")[0];
task[taskName] = cron.schedule(
  `0 */${process.env.TIME} * * *`,
  async () => {
    await deleteFile();
    event.emit("JOB_COMPLETED", taskName);
  }
);
event.on("JOB_COMPLETED", (completedTaskName: string) => {
  task[completedTaskName].stop();
});
...
```

the Idea is that you can change the time that the cron will run with the env vars,

testing my code, the problem is:

> using TIME= 1

with `0 */1 * * *`, the code is execute the next hour, I mean if time is 17:55 the code is executed at 18:00 and not at 18:55 (one hour later)

***What is the correct setting to run "TIME" hours after the cronjob was created and started?***

ex:

> TIME = 1

---

### if start at | run at

2:33        | 2:33 + TIME = 3:33

13:01       | 13:01 + TIME = 14: 01

20:15       | 20:15 + TIME = 21:15

> TIME = 3

---

### if start at | run at

2:33        | 2:33 + TIME = 5:33

13:01       | 13:01 + TIME = 16: 01

20:15       | 20:15 + TIME = 23:15

Comment: `0 */${process.env.TIME} * * *` instead of doing this, why not you are putting this whole string into env variable. For example store `55 * * * *`  this complete string into env variable if you want to run your cron on every 55th minutes.

Comment: @MunamTariq, ok but whats the configuration for X hours after cron was created/started

Answer (score 0):

Solved

getting the current minutues with `date.getMinutes()` to know after next hour how many minutos it needs to complete one hour:

```
var date = new Date;
...
cron.schedule(
      `${date.getMinutes()} */${process.env.TIME} * * *`,
      async () => {
...
```